# MVC 3 controller GroupBy View error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq

Im creating an MVC 3 view from a controller. My model "MyList", contains a large number of records. When I create my model using the following linq statement:

```
var model = _db.MyList.GroupBy(r => r.myKey);
```

I'm getting the error: "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.GenericlList' 1... but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' ...

In the view I have the following code in the first line:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyApp.Models.MyList>
```

I tried returning

```
return View(model.ToList());
```

from the controller, but no joy. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

`model.ToList()` will return a `List<T>` where `T` is MyList. Your model type is straight `MyList`. If the `var` declaration you have above already returns `MyList`, just do `return View(model)`.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I get the above mentioned error when I do the `return View(model)`

Answer (score 0):

This one was dogging me all morning. I found the answer to my question in the following post:

[Linq Distinct() by name for populate a dropdown list with name and value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/912188/linq-distinct-by-name-for-populate-a-dropdown-list-with-name-and-value)

I basically return the following:

```
public static IEnumberable<MyModel> FindTheKeys(this IQueryable<MyModel> myList)
{
    return myList.OrderBy(r => r.AreaKey);
}
```

and then performed the select as indicated in the above post.

```
var model = _db.MyModel.FindTheKeys().GroupBy(r => r.AreaKey).Select(g => g.First());
```

Answer (score -1):

GroupBy returns a collection of `IGrouping<TKey, TSource>`, not `MyList` (which is strange anyways, you wouldn't have a list of a list.

It doesn't even make much sense to convert a `GroupBy` into a list anyways.  Did you actuall mean `OrderBy`?

Comment: OrderBy returns too many records - GroupBy returns a subset of individual keys, e.g. each key would have several rows. Perhaps I should use DISTINCT on keys with OrderBy?

Comment: @soulia - No, Groupby returns just as many records, however it does so in multiple groups.  The overall number of records should be the same.  I can't say if using Distinct would be better, since I don't know your data model or your requirements.

Comment: Thanks! What I would like to do is return just the subset of records. For example, if my set was something like:
    -ID  SubKey Name   Age
    -1    10   tom    20
    -2    10   fred   21
    -3    11   sally  30
    -4    12   jill   32

My result set would be 10, 11, 12

Comment: Sorry, I'm having a touch time entering table data.