# Get distinct parameters from a List

Tags: c#, list

I have a `CarData` object with the following properties:
`PrimaryKey` `Make` `Model` `Year` `Drivetrain` `Country`

I have about 1000 of these `CarData` objects in a List :
`List<CarData> CarObjects`

Is there a simple way to get a list of the distinct `Make`s?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [Linq Distinct() by name for populate a dropdown list with name and value](http://stackoverflow.com/q/912188/299327)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var makes = CarObjects.Select(car => car.Make).Distinct();
```

This transforms the list from a list of `CarData` to a list of `Make`s, and then just finds the distinct values of the new list.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Linq:

```
CarObjects.Select ( c => c.Make ).Distinct().ToList()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var makeList = CarObjects.Select(a => a.Make).Distinct();
```

Or

```
List<MakeEnum> = CarObjects.Select(a => a.Make).Distinct().ToList();
```

As an extra bit of advice, you may want to consider having `Make` be an enum, since there are (presumably) a finite (and rather small) number of possible makes of cars, instead of piling them into `Strings`. (You don't make a mention of what kind of property `Make` is, so maybe you are already doing this).

Comment: @DanielHilgarth The call to `Distinct` was aded in a later edit.